# Implementing persistent associative array on top of LMDB

Tags: key-value, key-value-store, lmdb

I am new to key-value stores. I would like to try LMDB as persistent associative array and want to be able to use long length keys such as file paths or URLs.

LMDB defines compile-time constant MDB_MAXKEYSIZE=511 imposing a maximum for key length.

What technique should I use to implement persistent long-length key dictionary on top of LMDB? Some kind of hashing and collision resolution? Or recompile with different MAXKEYSIZE, for example 2048? Or LMDB is a wrong tool for this job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my own use, I handled a similar case by hashing the arbitrary-length string keys through [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) to produce a fixed-size 32-byte digest key for the B+ tree. This strategy entails the following two caveats:

1. You do altogether lose the ability to perform prefix string lookups. This isn't usually a significant problem for a use case such as the one you describe.
2. In case you need to be able to enumerate all the original string keys, you'll need to store the original strings in another LMDB sub-database such that you can perform a lookup based on a SHA-256 digest to retrieve its corresponding original string--which will have been stored as the value of a key/value pair in the sub-database, thus not subject to `MDB_MAXKEYSIZE` limits. This does increase space requirements, adds an additional tree lookup for every cursor operation in a full scan, and will not yield the strings in lexicographical order. If you can tolerate those limitations, this is a workable approach.

Comment: By the way, in case you are using LMDB from C++, you may be interested in my RAII-compatible wrapper library: https://github.com/bendiken/lmdbxx

Comment: Regarding point 2, a better approach in most cases is to store the key inside the lmdb value next to the original value using a simple binary encoding such as <keylen> <key> <value> (no need to store valuelen as it can be inferred).

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion of using a hashing algorithm to produce a shorter-length digest is excellent for cases where you don't need to preserve key order. However there are a lot of cases where order is important, and LMDB is still an awesome choice in those cases.

For example, if you're trying to look at all the files starting with the letter "x" in a common parent directory, then you want to preserve the order of the keys. You can certainly compile LMDB with a higher maximum key size in that case. But it's not the only strategy.

You can utilize an algorithm where the key digest preserves key order. You won't get as big a reduction in key size, but you'd be able to select the entire contents of a subdirectory as a contiguous group.

Or you can map a multidimensional structure onto your keys. Starting with root ID 0, each subdirectory is given a unique directory ID and the files and subdirectory entries are grouped inside a common parent directory ID.

```
[DirID,filename] = null - the null value means it's a file.
[DirID,dirname] = DIRID - the ID means it's a subdirectory.
```

This has a lot of benefits. The key length applies to each file and directory name, and not to the full directory path. So you don't have to recompile LMDB. It could also save memory, because the full path isn't repeated over and over again. And the file and directory sort order is preserved within each parent directory ID. Plus it opens the door to many persistent sparse matrix capabilities that you can build on top of this structure.

But full disclosure: there's also a downside. To obtain the full path or list the files in order, you'd have to keep recursing through subdirectories and you'd take multiple disk hits in the process.

So in the end, you have to look at what you are doing and where you will want to go in the future, and choose the most appropriate key design strategy for your specific case. If you get the key structure right, then you can hopefully avoid having to throw away all your code later, as you add new features.